# SQL Workbench/J set schema in tab

Tags: sql, schema, sql-workbench-j

How do I set the schema in an editor tab in SQL Workbench/J?

(something similar to "USE" in SQL Server/Management Studio)

in my interface (under the menu bar, to the right of the buttons), it shows I am in the "public" schema, but I can't figure out how to select a different one; I have a bunch of queries, and I'd like to not have to fully qualify every table

if it matters, I'm using RedShift as the database (don't know the version)
java version: 1.8.0_91-b15 (64bit)
SQL Workbench/J build: 118

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know or use Redshift, but as it's based on an (ancient version of) Postgres, [setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SET.html) the current schema should work:

```
set schema='other_schema';
```

Or change the [search_path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html):

```
set search_path=public, other_schema;
```

Note that for `set schema` the schema name needs to be put in single quotes, but **not** if you set the `search_path` (at least that's how Postgres works)

---

Build 118 is **really** old, you should update to a more recent version

Comment: the choice to upgrade is above my pay grade...for now; the first option above didn't work; the second option changed my schema to...public; so I reversed the order, and it worked; thanks

Comment: comment on *my* comment (meta-comment?): not being able to make a new line is a pain, and impedes readability